# Jssor slider is not working

Tags: slider, jssor

I replaced the original images with my own images in the simple-slider-source.html file in the non-jquery example folder and uploaded into the server along with the image folder and .js files but it doesn't work. It just running the slider without the images. Before uploading into my server, I have compiled it with the simple-slider.compress batch file. In case of original images it's working fine but not with the replaced images.

Is there anybody who can suggest any clue why it is happening and how to fix it? Providing sourcecode snippet would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute (url) of the `<img>` element is incorrect.